# Angular: directive after expressing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
<div editor>
    {{markdown.html}}
</div>
```

and following definition:

```
function editor() {
  return {
   restrict: "A",
   link: function (scope, element, attr) {
   jquery(element).summernote({
     height: 100,
     codemirror: {
       theme: 'monokai',
       mode: "text/html",
       lineNumbers: true,
       styleActiveLine: true,
       matchBrackets: true
     }});
    }
  };
}
```

Directive triggered before executing the expression.

How do you bind a model before executing the directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define:

```
<div editor markdown="markdown">
</div>
```

And then in your directive define an isolated scope, take the markdown variable, and use it in the link function:

```
function editor() {
  return {
   restrict: "A",
   scope: { markdown: "=" },
   link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      element.html(markdown.html)
      //activate your summernote
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular, you should not rely on the DOM (view). Following MVC means relying on the model (binding,updating,..) and let angular update the view based on your model, your code should not care about when the view is updated.

In case you do need, you could try a workaround with $timeout:

```
function editor($timeout) {
  return {
   restrict: "A",
   link: function (scope, element, attr) {
   $timeout(function(){
     jquery(element).summernote({
       height: 100,
       codemirror: {
         theme: 'monokai',
         mode: "text/html",
         lineNumbers: true,
         styleActiveLine: true,
         matchBrackets: true
       }
      });
     });
    }
  };
}
```